# How to setup vscode to open via cmd in windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmd

**Steps to setup windows to open your folder in vscode via cmd**

---

Today i have tried to open vscode via cmd in windows.

it gives and error. (code not found and recognized)

Then i have find out how to resolve that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to open folder in vscode following are the steps**

1. go to that folder
2. open cmd in that folder by just writing cmd on after clearing folder path and then hit enter
3. this will open cmd then check code version by just typing
   **code --version** in cmd
4. if it shows and error do the following steps (Here you will setup a path in environment variables)
5. open this folder in local disk c

> C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

6. Copy the above path
7. write edit the system environment variable in your windows search
   box near window icon (left bottom)
8. go to environmental variables then systems variables path click on
   path
9. New path then paste the file path of bin folder then click ok
10. now you can open your folder in vscode via cmd

Comment: you just need to add above bin folder path in system variables

Comment: Appdata folder is hidden folder in users folder